# What is considered a "normal melee attack" for Adept Cheap Shot?

Tags: attack, symbaroum

In the Symbaroum Advanced Player's Guide, the novice ability Cheap Shot reads as follows:

> **Active.** Cheap Shots like a “gutter-kiss”
> (head-butt) or a “goblin-squeeze” (groin
> kick) comes naturally to the character in
> stressful situations. Such an attack deals
> 1D6 damage, and if the opponent is damaged
> the character also gains a Free Attack
> against him or her.

The adept level Cheap Shot then provides the following effect:

> **Reaction.** The character performs a normal
> melee attack and if it deals damage, he or
> she adds a trip or a tackle. Such a maneuver
> knocks the opponent to the ground if the
> character succeeds with a [Cunning←Quick]
> test.

My question then is if the adept level effect applies to the free attack triggered in the novice ability, or if a "normal melee attack" restricts any use of novice Cheap Shot. This reading would restrict the effectiveness of Cheap Shot to choosing to gain a free attack or a trip on each turn. Given that tripping is only situationally useful, it seems that it would almost always be best to trigger free attacks instead, and spend the XP elsewhere.